# Low Events not showing correct category

Tags: low-events

I’m using Low Events and on the events index page I have a list of events, using the exp:low_events:entries tag.

On my event page, I’m using the normal channel:entries. Both work as should.

However on my event page which displays the event info I have the following categories code:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="events"
    date="{segment_2}"
    url_title="{segment_3}"
    show_expired="yes"
    status="open"
    show_passed="yes"
    show_future_entries="yes"
    limit="1"
}
```

This code works as should and shows the category assigned to the entry. However on the index page that uses the exp:low_events:entries tag, the event or events with the assigned category is not shown. Instead all events are listed.

I am missing some code in the categories code?

**edit**

```
{exp:low_events:entries
    channel="events"
    date="{segment_2}"
    category="{segment_3}"
    show_passed="yes"
    show_upcoming="yes"
    orderby="date"
    sort="asc"
    limit="5"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Low Events code? Can't really help you out if you don't share the code that's actually causing the issue. Adding the missing opening channel:entries tag in the example above would help, too.

Comment: Dear Low, Thank you for your reply. The missing opening code below is for the index page, that lists the events. This template is also used to display the categories. 

{exp:low_events:entries channel="events" date="{segment_2}" category="{segment_3}" show_passed="yes" show_upcoming="yes" orderby="date" sort="asc" limit="5"}

and this code is the missing opening events page code:

{exp:channel:entries channel="events" date="{segment_2}" url_title="{segment_3}" show_expired="yes" status="open" show_passed="yes" show_future_entries="yes" limit="1"}

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the two opening tags, here's my 2 cents.

In the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag, the `date` and `show_passed` parameters do nothing; they're used by the Low Events tag. Also, the tag will act [dynamically](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic).

In the `{exp:low_events:entries}` tag, you're using `category="{segment_3}"`, which will only work if `{segment_3}` **is a numeric category ID**. A category URL title *will not work*, as the category parameter [only accepts IDs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#category).